# GROUP By the CASE statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I would like to `GROUP BY` the `CASE` statement in SQL Server. I created cases that's my revenue range. I'd like to calculate the number of sales orders within all these revenue ranges (cases).

What I tried:

```
Select 
    sum(OrderQuantity) as Orders,
    case when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<100 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=0) then '$0-$100'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=100 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<500) then '$100-$500'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=500 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<1000) then '$500-$1000'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=1000 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<2500) then '$1000-$2500'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=2500 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<5000) then '$2500-$5000'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=5000 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<10000) then '$5000-$10000'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=10000 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<50000) then '$10000-$50000'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=50000 and sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<100000) then '$50000-$100000'
       when (sum(SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=100000) then '>$100000'
    end as SalesAmountCategory
From  
    dbo.FactResellerSales 
group by 
    SalesAmountCategory;
```

What I expect:

[image]

What I get:

> "Invalid column name 'SalesAmountCategory'"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for the error message. You don't need that `GROUP BY` just remove it. That alias of `SalesAmountCategory` is the result of an aggregate formula so it's unneeded as the group by. It's akin to saying `SELECT sum(sales) as sum_of_sales FROM some_table GROUP BY sum_of_sales;` which at best is superfluous and at worst throws an error (as it did here).

Comment: Hi there, i need to use the group by function coz i would like to sort the order numbers based on the cases i just created. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to know number of orders in each category

So, you need first to map each order to category and then group by it, like that:

```
select SalesAmountCategory, count(*) from
(
    Select case
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=100000) then '>$100000'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=50000) then '$50000-$100000'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=10000) then '$10000-$50000'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=5000) then '$5000-$10000'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=2500) then '$2500-$5000'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=1000) then '$1000-$2500'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=500) then '$500-$1000'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)>=100) then '$100-$500'
        when ((SalesAmount-TaxAmt-Freight)<100) then '$0-$100'
        end as SalesAmountCategory
    From  dbo.FactResellerSales 
) as t
group by SalesAmountCategory
```

Comment: Hi there sorry for the confusion. I would like to know the total order numbers that fall under each case category. That's why i use the sum function. e.g. I'd like to how many orders in total that falls under '$100-$500' this category.

Comment: @vivianna right, this is what this query does, to know how many orders - you need to `count` them, not `sum` quantity of products in it